# Google team drive and google colaboratory uploading/downloading files

Tags: colab

So I have google Team drive set-up with all the permissions.
1. How I can access google team drive in google colaboratory? I think i'm missing something... it's always showing me output of my drive
2. I want to download all the "data" from google team drive to my google colab notebook is it possible to make it automatically?

Comment: have you tried to upload it to your drive and using the id of the drive file?

Comment: so in order to upload all the files to my notebook in google colab in google team drive I need to have all the files in mydrive? and then will I be able to create so script to automatic download/upload all the data ?

Comment: That's a solution that I use. take a look at [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27964/how-to-download-dynamic-files-created-during-work-on-google-colab).