# How to save google colab notebook outputs and variables

Tags: python, colab

I want to save variables and outputs in text file with colab!

Any bright idea?

Answer (score 4):

Save your content in the current directory and execute `!dir` to see the content. Then follow the following code snippet:

```
from google.colab import files
files.download('your typical text file or what ever.txt')
```

For more information take a look at [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/27967/28175).

Comment: Thanks for replay, I didn't get it! how to save variable !? I have a matrix to save

Comment: I guess your question is irrelevant to the colab. You have a question about numpy arrays I guess. You can use `np.save` and `np.loadtxt` for storing and loading numpy matrices.

Comment: I'm new in python. All I want is just save some of my code's variables in text file, which they are mostly 2*2.

Comment: If they are numpy arrays use np.savetxt. If they are list, try to create numpy arrays and then save them. For doing so, use `np.array`.